# how to create dynamic attributes for different data types and store in mongodb

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I am facing problem regarding creating dynamic attributes with different data types (`int`, `boolean`, `float`, `double`, `long`, `String`, `byte`, ...) in Java using Spring Boot REST API and store in MongoDB collection. How can I get a solution for this?

```
@Field(value = "attributes")
Map<String, Object> attributes = new LinkedHashMap<>();

/*
 * setter for map attributes
 */
@JsonAnySetter
public void setAttributes(String key, Object value) {

    Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> s = attributes.entrySet();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> it : s) {
        key = it.getKey();
        value = it.getValue();
        this.attributes.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I am using this one but it's storing all data types as `String` only.
I need not require to store any value only I need to store attributes for particular data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly why your solution doesn't work. Try next:

Specify some class with your attributes:

```
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class User {
private Map<String, Object> attributes;

public User(Map<String, Object> attributes) {
    this.attributes = attributes;
}

public Object getAttribute() {
    return this.attributes;
}}
```

Specify mongodb repository:

```
interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID> {}
```

Controller to save dummy User:

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping("/save")
public User doSave() {
    Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();

    attributes.put("time", Instant.now());
    attributes.put("num", 5.6);
    attributes.put("str", "5.6");

    return userRepository.save(new User(attributes));
}
}
```

I got the next response:

```
{
"attribute": {
    "str": "5.6",
    "num": 5.6,
    "time": "2019-07-24T12:22:07.390Z"
}
}
```

The object in MongoDB:

[image]